# How to format zero values in R using prettyNum and zero.print

Tags: r

I would like `prettyNum` to handle zero values differently; for example, instead of printing "0", have it print "<0.01". I have been looking at the `zero.print` option but have only managed to get it print a single character. If for example you set zero.print="abc", only "a" will get printed (instead of "0").

Can you please let me know how to solve this problem? Or perhaps, `prettyNum` and `zero.print` it's not the way to go?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using:

```
print(ifelse(n==0, "<0.05", n))
```

`zero.print` seems to accept only 1 character (although the help file talks about "character string"...)

Comment: I didn't know about ifelse, and it seems to do the trick; nesting ifelse and prettyNum works well. Thanks!